# Best Practices: Including PHP in your JavaScript code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm a PHP phr34k addicted to JavaScript on the quest for some knowledge. If one were to include php code in their scripts, what would be the best method? I have provided some sample code as an example on how I would go about including PHP in my scripts.

Is this a valid method?

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP with JavaScript?</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js.php"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js.php**

```
<?php 

$foo = 'bar';

?>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var foo = '<?php echo $foo; ?>';
    alert(foo);
});
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried? (SPOILER, yes it works, but you're outputting JS through PHP, not including PHP in JS)

Comment: imho, best practice is not to mix php and javascript.

Comment: @Maxym what if I want a completely interactive page but also want people to be able to login? You'll need some way of letting the JS know who's logged in at the moment... putting it in an element and getting the contents of that isn't that much of a great idea either.

Comment: @Reanimation: Great point. Why do work when you could just... not?

Comment: @Reanimation: you just use AJAX in those cases, allowing you to separate what's happening server-side from what is happening client-side.

Comment: phr34k? j3ffz? What's with the leetspeak?

Comment: @Reanimation - when you simplify it this, you don't think about future support. I saw people acting that way, and I saw results (and I talk about badly mixed PHP+JS, and then they asked me about the way to it more scalable...)

Comment: @Reanimation, about your example - you can use AJAX, you can use cookies, you can print variables into html markup like in @Joyce Babu suggested,... enough possibilities to avoid PHP+JS

Comment: @Maxym, I do it Joyce Babu's way usually. Just seems to me there's no big difference in putting it at the end of your file or at the beginning, be it through a seperate file or not.

Comment: @Reanimation. JavaScript is cacheable on the client side, i.e. after user visited your page next time she won't load that script again (less pressure on server). It also depends on the header for script (you can deny caching). You can cache file in memory on server to send it quickly when client asks... Html is not cacheable, as well as when you write dynamic data with PHP in JS file then you are not able to cache that file at all, user will load it all the time making additional http requests... I'm limited here to explain all problems, but main idea I already wrote

Comment: @Maxym, oh I didn't know JS was cached as well ;x. I learn something new every day I am here, it seems xD.

Comment: @Dolph: Life plays according to my mood at that specific moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also set the content type header in test.js.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
```

You can also define `foo` inline like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP with JavaScript?</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = '<?php echo $foo;?>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
$(function(){
    alert(foo);
});
```

Comment: Btw, I don't remember whether it was `text/javascript` or `text/x-javascript`.

Comment: Either works. `application/x-javascript` is the proper way since it describes itself as non-standard, but any browser is going to accept any of them.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Why do we need a non-standard type? Isn't there an accepted/official type for Javascript?

Comment: Yes, and it's `application/x-javascript` I guess. My web server is serving up `.js` files with that MIME type too. http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Comment: Here's a little nugget of goodness: Note: According to IANA, the "text/javascript" MIME type is obsolete. The new standard is "application/javascript". However, "application/javascript" is not supported by Internet Explorer.

Comment: *However, "application/javascript" is not supported by Internet Explorer.* - As always

Answer (score 2):

I've seen people use the PHP interpreter to combine multiple JS source files before serving them to the client. That way the JS developers can benefit from having multiple files for more organized development but avoid sending multiple JS files (thus multiple HTTP requests) to the client.

However, these days there are several build scripts just for JavaScript. Sprockets, for example, allows you to automate building JavaScript files. Before that I considered it best practice to "compile" the JavaScript dependencies before hand. I wrote a simple Python script, for example, that would look for @include comments in JS source and order includes by their order of need. Probably better than wasting server time in exchange for a slight development convenience.

**EDIT**: Just take special care that you dump your variable data into the JavaScript properly. For example, if `$foo` is a string then you need to make sure that it's surrounded by double quotes. As is that code is going to go looking for a JavaScript variable called `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a *very* bizarre situation, what you've described isn't really possible.  PHP is evaluated on the server, while Javascript is sent to the user agent and executed by its Javascript engine (on the client side).

No user agents that I know of contain a PHP engine, so there's no way to have PHP executed on the client side.  Besides, unless you're use some heinous escapes, the PHP will be executed by the server anyway before the Javascript is sent to the client.

In the latter example you give, the PHP gets evaluated on the server and the client is sent a Javascript file that looks **exactly** like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var foo = 'bar';
    alert(foo);
});
```

So there's no PHP contained within the Javascript; rather, you're dynamically generating (normal) Javascript via PHP.

If this latter is what you intended, then yes - this works fine.  The PHP engine doesn't know anything about Javascript, and just generates some text that happens to have a particular meaning to a JS-parsing client.  So the presence of Javascript doesn't change *anything* on the PHP side, and since it's processed out, the (previous) presence of PHP doesn't change *anything* on the Javascript side.

(If you wanted your Javascript to execute some PHP on the client, however, that's fundamentally not possible.)

Comment: You can tell the server to send .js files through the PHP interpreter before they're served to the client so that you can serve up customized JavaScript code. Notice his source files ends in `.js.php`.

Comment: Yes - however, those (generated/customised) JavaScript files sent to the client won't actually *contain* PHP, which is what I understand j3ffz is after.

Comment: The `.php` extension is going to cause the web server to send the file through the PHP interpreter, so all that PHP code is going to be processed before being sent.

Comment: That was exactly the point of my first comment: he's outputting JS through PHP, just as you could output HTML through PHP, nothing more.

Comment: @Andrew - I agree, that's exactly what I described in the third paragraph.  Since the PHP gets interpreted by the server, what we end up is (plain old) Javascript generated by PHP; and *not* "PHP included in the Javascript", as asked for.